FilamentPHP + Spatie Media library plugin: Images are not being saved
I am using FilamentPHP and Spatie media library. Additionally, I am using the Spatie media library FilamentPHP plugin in order to show and upload the images in my admin panel.
However, the images are not being uploaded and stored at all!
This is my model:
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\HasMedia;
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\InteractsWithMedia;

class OrderItem extends Model implements HasMedia
{
    use InteractsWithMedia;

    public function registerMediaCollections(): void
    {
        $this->addMediaCollection('designs')
            ->useDisk('designFiles');
    }
}

My filesystem.php:
'designFiles' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => storage_path('app/public/designs'),
    'url' => env('APP_URL') . '/storage/designs',
    'visibility' => 'public',
],

My filament resource:
SpatieMediaLibraryFileUpload::make('design')
    ->collection('designs')
    ->downloadable()
    ->multiple(),

The image I upload on my filament resource are being stored temporarily at storage/app/livewire-tmp. However, there is no entry in my spatie media library media table and the image is also not being saved to the desired disk (designFiles).
I have already tried to debug this problem but there is no error event being logged at all. I am using Laravel Valet and I have also added the port to my APP_URL variable with my .env file as suggested here but it did not help me.
I have also run php artisan storage:link but because I did run this command before already, it did not change anything. The image is still not being saved.
Those are the versions I use:
"php": "^8.2",
"filament/filament": "^3.2",
"filament/spatie-laravel-media-library-plugin": "^3.2",
"laravel/framework": "^11.9",
"spatie/laravel-medialibrary": "^11.8"

Anybody has an idea how to fix this problem?
Kind regards
UPDATE Added minimal reproducible example
Because it was requested, I have added a minimal reproducible example. Sadly, I am still facing the same issue! You can get it here: https://github.com/FrazeColder/example-app and login to Filament on /admin/login with the credentials you find in the database/seeders/DatabaseSeeder.php 

Is the image deleted from storage/app/livewire-tmp?

@KalenGi no it is not! It stays in the folder!

You say "the images are not being uploaded and stored at all" but then you say "the image I upload on my filament resource are being stored temporarily at storage/app/livewire-tmp" which would suggest they are being uploaded. Can you clarify? I am not familiar with Filament, but I see no code here that looks like it would move that file into the storage disk. Include a [mre] in your question, including minimal front-end form code, relevant controller methods, and applicable route definitions.

To clearify: The image get uploaded to storage/app/livewire-tmp but they don't get saved to the specific model. There is no database entry in the media table, but also no error being logged or thrown.

@KalenGi I have added a minimal reproducible example above to my question

@Jan the minimal example has an error: Class "App\Filament\Resources\Timeline" not found in \app\Filament\Resources\OrderResource.php line 53

@Jan there's also no way to create an OrderItem. The Order does not have this provision, and there is no explicit OrderItem create button

@KalenGi you can get rid of the Timeline item. OrderItems should be created when you run the seed command for the database :)

This is not exactly a solution as I do not have a clear picture of your precise setup, but it may help you track down the problem.
I applied the parameters that you specified and my media files were successfully saved to the correct location (app/public/designs). I however used "spatie/laravel-medialibrary": "^11.9"
Add the following code to have a finer-grained view of what is going on when you save an OrderItem:
app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Illuminate\Database\Events\QueryExecuted;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     */
    public function boot(): void
    {
        DB::listen(function(QueryExecuted $query) {
            $is_insert = strpos($query->sql, "insert into") !== false;
            $is_orderitem = strpos($query->sql, "order_items") !== false;
            $is_mediaitem = strpos($query->sql, "media") !== false;
            if ($is_insert && ($is_orderitem || $is_mediaitem)) {
                Log::info(
                    $query->sql,
                    [
                        'bindings' => $query->bindings,
                        'time' => $query->time
                    ]
                );
            }
            
        });
    }
}

This should log any queries that insert to order_items or a media. I've assumed these are the names you have for the matching tables in your database. If the names you are using are different, then update the code accordingly.
The logged transactions can be viewed in storage/logs/laravel.log. Newer log entries are at the very end of the file.
In the case of a successful creation of an OrderItem, the log file should contain lines beginning with:

[TIME_STAMP] local.INFO: insert into 'order_items'...
[TIME_STAMP] local.INFO: insert into 'media'...

The media file gets copied to app/public/designs after insert into 'media'... has succeeded. Lastly, the uploaded temporary file is deleted from storage/app/livewire-tmp.
With these insights, you can figure out at what point the problem is occurring. If order_items has a new entry, but there isn't a matching one in media, then the process failed before handling the media.
My best guess is that you have a file permissions problem that prevents the copying of storage/app/livewire-tmp/image.png to app/public/designs/image.png. And just to be sure, you can try to save an OrderItem that does not have any media fields so as to establish there isn't any other non-media related issue.
UPDATE
Working with the minimal reproducible example that you supplied, I was able to track down the issue. You have the following implementation of the EditOrderItem::save() method:
public function save(bool $shouldRedirect = true, bool $shouldSendSavedNotification = true): void
{
    Notification::make()
        ->title('Saved successfully')
        ->success()
        ->send();
}

This implementation masks EditRecord::save(), which is the parent method that should complete the save operation. You need to invoke the parent save() method so it can do it's job as normal. Here's the code:
public function save(bool $shouldRedirect = true, bool $shouldSendSavedNotification = true): void
{
    parent::save($shouldRedirect, $shouldSendSavedNotification);
    
    Notification::make()
        ->title('Saved successfully')
        ->success()
        ->send();
}

This now allows the images to be copied to app/public/designs as expected.

1. In your controller or a tinker session, try something like this:
$orderItem = OrderItem::find(1); // OrderItem ID
$orderItem->addMedia($pathToFile) // path to a file
    ->toMediaCollection('designs');

2.Also check the configuration
SpatieMediaLibraryFileUpload::make('design')
    ->collection('designs')
    ->disk('designFiles')
    ->downloadable()
    ->multiple(),

3.Try to check storage permissions
sudo chmod -R 775 storage
sudo chown -R $USER:www-data storage

In this you can create debug log as well to check and verify that Filament resource saves the data.

Thank you for your answer. I can confirm, that I can add an image to my media collection designs, as you wrote in n1. I have also added ->disk('designFiles') to my FilamentPHP Resrouce as you suggest in n2 and run sudo chmod -R 775 storage. But its still not saving the image to the model. However, I was not able to execute sudo chown -R $USER:www-data storage. Do I need to replace anything? I get chown: www-data: illegal group name. I am developing on a MacBook
